# Implicit super constructor is undefined - Java error

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

I am using the following UML and some directions to write a program.[image]

I am currently working on the Butterfly class. Below is what I have so far.

```
package nuisance;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author brand
 *
 */
public class Butterfly extends Insect {

    private List<String> colors;

    /**
     * @param species
     */
    public Butterfly(String species, List<String> colors) {
        super(species);
        this.colors = colors;
    }

    public Butterfly(Butterfly butterfly) {
        this.butterfly = butterfly;
    }
```

The issue I am having is in the second constructor which is supposed to initialize the fields based on an existing Butterfly object. I feel like I have written it correctly, but I am getting the following error:

Implicit super constructor Insect() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor.

I have done some research on this and I can't seem to figure out how to fix the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you don’t call super explicitly you get a call to super inserted for you. Which doesn’t work if the super class doesn’t have a no-arg constructor. Also this.butterfly is not an instance member.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your copy constructor,

```
public Butterfly(Butterfly butterfly) {
    this.butterfly = butterfly;
}
```

has an implicit call to `super()` as the first line. Like,

```
public Butterfly(Butterfly butterfly) {
    super();
    this.butterfly = butterfly;
}
```

And there is no empty `Insect` constructor. Use `Butterfly.getSpecies()` and `Butterfly.getColors()` to perform the copy with a `this` constructor call. Like,

```
public Butterfly(Butterfly butterfly) {
    this(butterfly.getSpecies(), butterfly.getColors());
}
```

Comment: That would be a shallow copy, since the list of colors will be shared, and `List` is very likely mutable. Still, shallow copy might be ok, so +1 from me.

Comment: @Andreas You're not wrong, but OP has `this.colors = colors;` in their first constructor. Which is where I would put the copy (do it once there - but that's just my opinion); `this.colors = new ArrayList<>(colors);`

Comment: Not exactly sure which one is correct (shallow vs deep) but you guys definitely cleared up the original issue I was having, and I understand why as well. Cannot thank you enough!

Comment: @BrandonBischoff Ask yourself this, should changing the colors of one butterfly change the colors of the copies of that butterfly? If yes, you want a ***shallow*** copy. If no, you want ***deep*** copy.

Answer (score 1):

`this.butterfly` will fail to compile, because you don't have a field named `butterfly` (and you shouldn't).

Your copy-constructor should be:

```
public Butterfly(Butterfly butterfly) {
    super(butterfly.getSpecies());
    this.colors = new ArrayList<>(butterfly.colors); // deep copy
}
```